# "Global symbol requires explicit package name" even when the variable is declared

Tags: perl, fasta, fastq

I'm trying to convert fastq file to fasta file. Here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use vars;

my $input=$ARGV[0];
my $output=$ARGV[1];
my $qual_length = 0
```

and this is error message

```
syntax error at newfastq.pl line 9, near "my "
Global symbol "$seq_length" requires explicit package name at newfastq.pl line 9.
Global symbol "$seq_length" requires explicit package name at newfastq.pl line 24.
Global symbol "$seq_length" requires explicit package name at newfastq.pl line 31.
Global symbol "$seq_length" requires explicit package name at newfastq.pl line 39.
```

I don't understand this error because I declared $seq_length in the beginning.
What is wrong?
And I can't check my algorithm is right or not.

Comment: By the way, just like you simplified `$_ =~ s/.../.../` to `s/.../.../`, you can simplify `$_ =~ /.../` to `/.../`

Comment: @ikegami Ok I will try

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `;` in the line before the declaration of `$seq_length`

Comment: ah got it Thanks!